# Why does my shower divert drip even after replacing the stem?

Tags: plumbing

I changed the diverter stem for my 3 handle shower/tub. We only use the shower but when I turn the diverter to tub the water drips a little from the diverter handle. Being we never use the tub I will just leave the diverter turned to shower as it does not drip on the shower selection.

What is causing this to drip when I turn the handle to the tub selection, as it's a new diverter valve stem? It's a Price Pfister diverter valve 4.25 inches in length. I made sure I put the washer in place before installing. The seat was still ok no nicks or briars so I did not change that.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the seal is still not performing at 100%.  Try removing it again check that it didn't get nicked during the first assembly and reassemble with a little
[Great White compound](https://www.acehardware.com/departments/plumbing/solvents-and-cements/plumbers-putty-and-sealers/4396321?store=15404&gclid=CjwKCAjw4ZWkBhA4EiwAVJXwqflGrv9QKRytLBEgPRYMvzG-ZBOZC1hXD1GZ7ni7tmHP5E85UX9d0RoCs-gQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) on the stem.

Comment: Thank you... I'll try that. I did Teflon tape the threads single layer prior to installing. I will take it apart again and look at it. The faucet is 7 years old.